# Facing some errors while implementing a class component method to functional component method in a restaurant rating management project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

***RestaurantList.js***

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
export default class RestaurantList extends Component {
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  list: null,
};
}

componentDidMount() {
fetch("http://localhost:3000/restaurant").then((response) => {
  response.json().then((result) => {
    this.setState({ list: result });
  });
});
}
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <h1>List</h1>
    {
      this.state.list ?
        <div>
          <Table striped bordered hover>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Operation</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {
                this.state.list.map((item, i) =>
                  <tr>
                    <td>{item.id}</td>
                    <td>{item.name}</td>
                    <td>{item.email}</td>
                    <td>{item.rating}</td>
                    <td>{item.address}</td>
                    <td><Link to={"/update/" + item.id} style={{ color: 'blue', textDecoration: 'inherit' }}>Edit</Link></td>
                  </tr>)
              }
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </div>
        :
        <p>Please Wait...</p>
    }
  </div>
);
}
}
```

***RestaurantUpdate.js***

**In Class Component Method (It is correct)**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NavBarManu from './NavBarManu'

class RestaurantUpdate extends Component {
constructor()
{
    super();
    this.state = {
    name: null,
    email: null,
    address: null,
    rating: null,
    id:null,
   }
}
componentDidMount()
{ 
   fetch('http://localhost:3000/restaurant/'+this.props.match.params.id).then((response) => {
        response.json().then((result) => {
            console.warn(result)
             this.setState({ 
                 name:result.name,
                 email:result.email,
                 id:result.id,
                 rating:result.rating,
                 address:result.address

              })
        })
    })
}
update()
{
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/restaurant/'+this.state.id, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
    }).then((result)=>{
        result.json().then((resp)=>{
            alert("Restaurant has heen Update")
        })
    })
}
render() {
    
    return (
        <div>
            <NavBarManu />
            <h1>Restaurant Update</h1>
            <div>
                <input onChange={(event) => { this.setState({ name: event.target.value }) }}
                    placeholder="Restaurant Name" value={this.state.name} /> <br /><br />
                <input onChange={(event) => { this.setState({ email: event.target.value }) }}
                    placeholder="Restaurant Email" value={this.state.email} /> <br /><br />
                <input onChange={(event) => { this.setState({ rating: event.target.value }) }}
                    placeholder="Restaurant Rating"  value={this.state.rating}/> <br /><br />
                <input onChange={(event) => { this.setState({ address:    event.target.value }) }}
                       placeholder="Restaurant Address"  value={this.state.address}/> <br       /><br />
                   <button onClick={() => { this.update() }}>Update Restaurant</button>
               </div>
           </div>
       );
   }
}

export default RestaurantUpdate;
```

**In Functional Component(Facing some errors)**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const RestaurantUpdate = () => {
const [name, setName] = useState(null);
const [email, setEmail] = useState(null);
const [address, setAddress] = useState(null);
const [rating, setRating] = useState(null);
const [id, setId] = useState(null);



//Want to use it like CompoundDidMount
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/restaurant' / +id).then((response) => {
        response.json().then((result) => {
            console.warn(result)
            setName(result.name);
            setEmail(result.email);
            setId(result.id);
            setAddress(result.address);
            setRating(result.rating);
        })
    })
}, []);
//Want to display all the states in the console with their respective values. But i am unable to do it.
useEffect(() => {
    console.warn(name);
}, [id]);
return (
    <div>
        <h1>Update</h1>
        <div>
            <input onChange={(event) => { this.setState({ name: event.target.value }) }}
                placeholder="Restaurant Name" /> <br /><br />
            <input onChange={(event) => { this.setState({ email: event.target.value }) }}
                placeholder="Restaurant Email" /> <br /><br />
            <input onChange={(event) => { this.setState({ rating: event.target.value }) }}
                placeholder="Restaurant Rating" /> <br /><br />
            <input onChange={(event) => { this.setState({ address: event.target.value }) }}
                placeholder="Restaurant Address" /> <br /><br />
            <button onClick={() => { this.update() }}>Update Restaurant</button>
        </div>
    </div>
);
};

export default RestaurantUpdate;
```

I was expecting display of all the state in the console with the their respective data. But it is showing null values.
I am facing some errors in implementing componentDidMount() in function component using hooks and in setState().
Basically I just want to use given Class Component RestaurantUpdate.js in functional component way.
Definitely there are some syntax errors and i am facing some difficulties in implementing them. So please point out the error and provide me the right solution.

> Blockquote

Comment: Your first `useEffect` should have an empty dependency array `[]` so that it only gets called once.

Comment: @andy ok done but after that? My issue was different btw

Answer (score 0):

Add a conditional render and see if it works.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const RestaurantUpdate = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState(null);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState(null);
    const [address, setAddress] = useState(null);
    const [rating, setRating] = useState(null);
    const [id, setId] = useState(null);
    const [result, setResult] = useState(null);



    //Want to use it like CompoundDidMount
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/restaurant' / +id).then((response) => {
            response.json().then((result) => {
                console.warn(result)
                setResult(result);
                setName(result.name);
                setEmail(result.email);
                setId(result.id);
                setAddress(result.address);
                setRating(result.rating);
            })
        })
    }, []);
    //Want to display all the states in the console with their respective values. But i am unable to do it.
    useEffect(() => {
        console.warn(name);
    }, [id]);
    return (
        <>
            {
                result ? (
                    <div>
                        <h1>Update</h1>
                        <div>
                            <input onChange={(event) => { setName(event.target.value) }} value={name}
                                placeholder="Restaurant Name" /> <br /><br />
                            <input onChange={(event) => { setEmail(event.target.value) }} value={email}
                                placeholder="Restaurant Email" /> <br /><br />
                            <input onChange={(event) => { setRating(event.target.value) }} value={rating}
                                placeholder="Restaurant Rating" /> <br /><br />
                            <input onChange={(event) => { setAddress(event.target.value) }} value={address}
                                placeholder="Restaurant Address" /> <br /><br />
                            <button onClick={() => { update() }}>Update Restaurant</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ) : (<div>loading</div>)
            }
        </>


    );
};

export default RestaurantUpdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to address here that probably will help you to achieve the desired result.

First is the `id`, probably it should come from the a call to `useParams` right? if so, no need to declare it as a state.

```
const { id } = useParams();
```

Then, in the `useEffect` even though you want to simulate `compoundDidMount` the recommended solution is to include in the deps array all the values used internally in the `useEffect`. this link [hooks docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) is super helpful.

Next, you probably is having some warnings in the `console` complaining about `"value" prop on "input" should not be null` and `A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled`, this can be avoided just by setting an initial state for the inputs different of `null` or `undefined`, and this could be:

```
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
  const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
```

or also by using the technique displayed in the previous answers will help you to remove from these warnings.

Also in your example the `value` field was missing in the `inputs`

```
<input 
   onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)} 
   placeholder="Restaurant Name" 
   value={name} />
```

And I guess with these tweaks you should be fine. I've put together a sandbox that might help you to unfold everything. [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-playground-restaturant-fy63td)

Comment: Yeah i got it. Perfect explaination. Btw we can use //setName(event.target.value )}// instead of //setName({ name: event.target.value })} //. Bcoz setName will change the name only. It wont change any other element. So it is not necessary to mention name: event.target.value . Am i right? Bcoz it is working for me

Comment: you're completely right, will update the answer to be correct.